# DataStax DevCenter schema window always empty

Tags: cassandra

After successfully connecting to Cassandra, creating few keyspaces and tables the DevCenter Schema window suddenly got empty.

It is not showing any content and stays empty even after restarting DevCenter and reinstalling DevCenter (including erasing the .devcenter directory under my user home) a couple of times.

At the DevCenter default_1.cql window "in keyspace" dropdown I can see the keyspaces in the dropdown list

Using cqlsh I can see all the key spaces and tables there.

Environment info: DevCenter 1.4.1 running on latest Mac OS and Cassandra 2.2.1 running on latest Centos7.

Any ideas of what could be the cause  and how to solve it ?

Thanks.

The following stacktrace was found at DevCenter error log (About DevCenter -> Installation Details -> View Error log)

```
    !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2015-09-08 07:27:19.757
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: STATUS_ID is not a field defined in this definition
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.executeItem(HandledContributionItem.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(HandledContributionItem.java:701)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.access$6(HandledContributionItem.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem$4.handleEvent(HandledContributionItem.java:613)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4199)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1467)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1490)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1475)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1279)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4042)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3669)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at com.datastax.devcenter.rcp.Application.start(Application.java:22)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: STATUS_ID is not a field defined in this definition
    at com.datastax.driver.core.UserType.getFieldType(UserType.java:165)
    at com.datastax.devcenter.schema.SchemaInitializer.getDataTypeMapping(SchemaInitializer.java:611)
    at com.datastax.devcenter.schema.SchemaInitializer.getDataTypeMapping(SchemaInitializer.java:587)
    at com.datastax.devcenter.schema.SchemaInitializer.loadColumnMetaData(SchemaInitializer.java:418)
    at com.datastax.devcenter.schema.SchemaInitializer.loadTableMetaData(SchemaInitializer.java:378)
    at com.datastax.devcenter.schema.SchemaInitializer.loadMetaDataFromDriver(SchemaInitializer.java:328)
    at com.datastax.devcenter.schema.SchemaInitializer.init(SchemaInitializer.java:122)
    at com.datastax.devcenter.cql.ui.wizards.ddl.DDLWizard.getActiveSchema(DDLWizard.java:211)
    at com.datastax.devcenter.cql.ui.wizards.ddl.KeyspaceWizard.createModel(KeyspaceWizard.java:61)
    at com.datastax.devcenter.cql.ui.wizards.ddl.DDLWizard.init(DDLWizard.java:128)
    at com.datastax.devcenter.cql.ui.wizards.ddl.DDLWizard.init(DDLWizard.java:111)
    at com.datastax.devcenter.cql.ui.handlers.ddl.NewKeyspaceHandler.createWizard(NewKeyspaceHandler.java:18)
    at com.datastax.devcenter.cql.ui.handlers.ddl.DDLHandler.execute(DDLHandler.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    ... 40 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2015-09-08 07:27:34.940
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4441)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4356)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3994)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3671)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at com.datastax.devcenter.rcp.Application.start(Application.java:22)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:418)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:431)
    at com.datastax.devcenter.cql.CqlContext.getLastSchema(CqlContext.java:116)
    at com.datastax.devcenter.cql.CqlContext.getSchema(CqlContext.java:135)
    at com.datastax.devcenter.cql.CqlContext.getDatabaseSchema(CqlContext.java:104)
    at com.datastax.devcenter.schema.ui.views.SchemaTreeViewPart.updateTreeViewerInput(SchemaTreeViewPart.java:142)
    at com.datastax.devcenter.schema.ui.views.SchemaTreeViewPart.access$2(SchemaTreeViewPart.java:135)
    at com.datastax.devcenter.schema.ui.views.SchemaTreeViewPart$1.run(SchemaTreeViewPart.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:136)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: I ended up deleting the keyspaces I had created and  after that the DevCenter  window is working again.

Answer (score 1):

From the stack trace, it looks like the java driver used by DevCenter to connect to Cassandra was unable to find the user-defined type field "STATUS_ID" when asked for it's data type.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: STATUS_ID is not a field defined in this definition
at com.datastax.driver.core.UserType.getFieldType(UserType.java:165)
at com.datastax.devcenter.schema.SchemaInitializer.getDataTypeMapping(SchemaInitializer.java:611)
```

This should not happen as the list of field names was retrieved directly from the java driver.

I was able to reproduce this problem and I think the root cause is a case-sensitivity problem with the java driver, although DevCenter should handle this better too. I filed [JAVA-962](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-962) for the java driver.

Thanks for asking/reporting this.